# What does [ "$var" ] && $var do?

Tags: shell, sh

I was going through a codebase and came across the following piece of code in a shell script:

```
./some_script.sh 
errcode=$?

if [ "$errcode" != 0 ]; then
  [ "$SCRIPT_PATH" ] && $SCRIPT_PATH do_something
fi
```

`SCRIPT_PATH` is an environment variable which expands to the path of a script (say `/usr/bin/abc.sh`). However, I do not understand what the code in the if loop does. What does `[ "$SCRIPT_PATH" ]` do? Is there any use of it or was this just something written incorrectly? Only thing I can think of is that it was supposed to be `[ -f "$SCRIPT_PATH" ]` to check if file exists before running it, but I'm not sure anymore.

Any idea what else this could be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs the program in `SCRIPT_PATH` *if it is not empty or unset* (because that's what the `[ one_arg ]` test does.)

Comment: Note that this is a VERY NAIVE approach. Better to use `[ -x "$SCRIPT_PATH" ]` which tests that the script exists, and that is executable.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer That is a valuable piece of advice.

Comment: `$SCRIPT_PATH` should also be quoted when it is finally used, unlike in the original snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shorthand for the following:

```
if [ "$errcode" != 0 ]; then
  if [ "$SCRIPT_PATH" ]; then
     $SCRIPT_PATH do_something
  fi
fi
```

It works by abusing the way chained conditions "short circuit" in an `if` statement.

Whether this is a good idea is … debatable.